# Adding values to string array dynamically, shows null values as result on displaying array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to insert string values in an String array and after adding these values I want to sort them. But the problem is after inserting all the values to the string array when I loop through the array I get null values as the output !!!

Insertion of values in

```
String string;
int number, index = 0;
string = br.readLine();
number = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
String[] temp = new String[string.length()*number];

for(int i=0; i<=string.length()-number; i++)
{    
    temp[index] = string.substring(i, i+number);
    System.out.println(temp[index]);
    index++;
}
```

Sorting values

```
System.out.println("\nBefore sorting");

for(int i=0; i<index; i++)        
    System.out.print(temp[index]+" ");

for(int i=index-1; i>0; i--)
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
        if(temp[j].compareTo(temp[j+1]) < 0)
        {
            String swap = temp[j];
            temp[j] = temp[j+1];
            temp[j+1] = swap;
        }

System.out.println("\nAfter sorting");
for(int i=0; i<index; i++)        
    System.out.print(temp[index]+" ");
```

The output I get is

> aakash 
>   3
>   aak
>   aka
>   kas
>   ash 
>   Before sorting
>   null null null null
>   After sorting
>   null null null null

I cannot understand where this null values come from! The contents of my array should ideally be temp[aak aka kas ash] but it comes out to be temp[null null null null]

Please help me point out with what mistake I am making in this code.

Comment: Try a debugger please

Comment: You might want to use `Arrays.sort()` instead of implementing a custom sorting algorithm.

Comment: Why `new String[string.length() * number]`? What do you think this does?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose this statements creates an array temp of mentioned size ie `string.length() * number`. The purpose to create an array is to store the substring values from the input string.

Comment: @AakashGoplani Then you should do a little math, and first calculate the exact number of substrings, then second calculate what `string.length() * number` results in.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Okay, I will do that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Everything works, the problem that you have is, that you are not printing the array of strings correctly.
Your code:

```
for(int i=0; i<index; i++)        
    System.out.print(temp[index]+" ");
```

should be:

```
for(int i=0; i<index; i++)        
   System.out.print(temp[i]+" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your code once again carefully.

```
    for(int i=0; i<index; i++)        
       System.out.print(temp[index]+" ");
```

And if you still can't figure out, just print value of index variable before
executing your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You were using `index` instead of `i`. As a result the program was working 
but you were displaying `arra[index]` while index was 4 and you only had 3 elements in the array.

Please change

```
System.out.println("\nBefore sorting");
for(int i=0; i<index; i++)        
    System.out.print(temp[index]+" ");
```

to

```
System.out.println("\nBefore sorting");
for(int i=0; i<index; i++)        
    System.out.print(temp[i]+" ");
```